# vue render the loop element, the result is not I think

Tags: vue.js

code:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="b in a">
        <div v-if ="b === 3" >
            {{ c++ }}
        </div>
        <p>{{ b }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
......
......
data() {
    return {
        a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        c: 0
    }
},
......
```

my question is why c is not print 1, 2

the result is 202, 203

It looks run 100 times before rendering

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating an endless recursion, where every time you render `c`, you increment it afterward (`c++`), which means that you have to render it again, thus incrementing it again, and here we go...

In dev mode, Vue tracks the recursion and breaks out of it, apparently after around 200 iterations. It also prints an info message in the console about it:

> [Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.

In production, Vue does not interfere, so your page would just freeze.